# Pay for Access Areas in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I want to build a wordpress site that shows some content to all, and then only shows the rest of the content to people who have paid either via paypal or credit card. Moreover, I want this access to happen automatically upon payment (if possible), i.e. I don't have to manually give that person access after I check to make sure they have paid.

Is there a way to do this in wordpress or would something like rails/django be more appropriate?

Comment: Your first port of call should be Wordpress' plugin repository. I'm fairly sure plugins exist for this

Comment: Nope, I haven't dealt with this myself

Answer (score 2):

The [s2member plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/s2member/) will take care of this for you.